# Neovim clangd not indexing all include files

Tags: cmake, neovim, clangd, nvim-lspconfig

I have a massive C project that is build by cmake, I generate the `compile_commands.json` and all the includes are there, but for example in main.c it cannot find `libxml/parser.h`.

In the `compile_commands.json` `main.c` is compiled with

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc [...] -I[path/to/project]/sdk/include [...] -o CMakeFiles/standard_project.dir/main.c.obj   -c C:/Users/gianl/Desktop/ite_sdk/project/standard_project/main.c
```

(I will not include the [...] because it has way to many options)

`libxml/parser.h` is in `[path/to/project]/sdk/include` yet still clangd can't find it.

I'm using clangd version `Ubuntu clangd version 12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.5` in Neovim v0.7.2
This is my init.vim for clangd (note that I'm using clangd-12)

```
-- Use an on_attach function to only map the following keys
-- after the language server attaches to the current buffer
local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  -- Enable completion triggered by <c-x><c-o>
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, 'omnifunc', 'v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc')

  -- Mappings.
  -- See `:help vim.lsp.*` for documentation on any of the below functions
  local bufopts = { noremap=true, silent=true, buffer=bufnr }
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gD', vim.lsp.buf.declaration, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gi', vim.lsp.buf.implementation, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-k>', vim.lsp.buf.signature_help, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>wa', vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>wr', vim.lsp.buf.remove_workspace_folder, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>wl', function()
    print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()))
  end, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>D', vim.lsp.buf.type_definition, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>rn', vim.lsp.buf.rename, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>ca', vim.lsp.buf.code_action, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', 'gr', vim.lsp.buf.references, bufopts)
  vim.keymap.set('n', '<alt>L', vim.lsp.buf.formatting, bufopts)
end

local lsp_flags = {
  -- This is the default in Nvim 0.7+
  debounce_text_changes = 150,
}
require('lspconfig')['pyright'].setup{
    on_attach = on_attach,
    flags = lsp_flags,
}
require('lspconfig')['tsserver'].setup{
    on_attach = on_attach,
    flags = lsp_flags,
}
require('lspconfig')['rust_analyzer'].setup{
    on_attach = on_attach,
    flags = lsp_flags,
    -- Server-specific settings...
    settings = {
      ["rust-analyzer"] = {}
    }
}
require('lspconfig').clangd.setup{
    on_attach = on_attach,
    flags = lsp_flags,
    cmd = {"clangd-12"}
}
```

I've had the same problem with `ccls` it might be because the project is so big (1000 compile commands each with 5700 chars in length)

**EDIT**

Clangd log (not verbose if any one know how to enable it I will post the output)

```
[START][2022-08-12 06:28:15] LSP logging initiated
[ERROR][2022-08-12 06:28:18] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:420    "rpc"   "clangd-12" "stderr"    "I[06:28:18.108] Ubuntu clangd version 12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.5\nI[06:28:18.108] PID: 185\n"
[ERROR][2022-08-12 06:28:18] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:420    "rpc"   "clangd-12" "stderr"    "I[06:28:18.109] Working directory: /mnt/c/Users/gianl/Desktop/ite_sdk\nI[06:28:18.109] argv[0]: clangd-12\n"
[ERROR][2022-08-12 06:28:18] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:420    "rpc"   "clangd-12" "stderr"    "I[06:28:18.109] Starting LSP over stdin/stdout\n"
[ERROR][2022-08-12 06:28:18] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:420    "rpc"   "clangd-12" "stderr"    "I[06:28:18.109] <-- initialize(1)\n"
[ERROR][2022-08-12 06:28:18] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:420    "rpc"   "clangd-12" "stderr"    "I[06:28:18.134] --> reply:initialize(1) 24 ms\n"
[ERROR][2022-08-12 06:28:33] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:420    "rpc"   "clangd-12" "stderr"    "I[06:28:33.828] <-- initialized\n"
[ERROR][2022-08-12 06:28:33] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:420    "rpc"   "clangd-12" "stderr"    "I[06:28:33.828] <-- textDocument/didOpen\n"
[ERROR][2022-08-12 06:28:33] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:420    "rpc"   "clangd-12" "stderr"    "I[06:28:33.857] Loaded compilation database from /mnt/c/Users/gianl/Desktop/ite_sdk/compile_commands.json\n"
[ERROR][2022-08-12 06:28:33] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:420    "rpc"   "clangd-12" "stderr"    "I[06:28:33.857] ASTWorker building file /mnt/c/Users/gianl/Desktop/ite_sdk/project/standard_project/main.c version 0 with command clangd fallback\n[/mnt/c/Users/gianl/Desktop/ite_sdk/project/standard_project]\n/usr/bin/clang /mnt/c/Users/gianl/Desktop/ite_sdk/project/standard_project/main.c -fsyntax-only -resource-dir=/usr/lib/llvm-12/lib/clang/12.0.0\n"
[ERROR][2022-08-12 06:28:33] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:420    "rpc"   "clangd-12" "stderr"    "I[06:28:33.997] --> textDocument/publishDiagnostics\n"
```

I've just found this error in an older log:

```
[ERROR][2022-08-12 06:25:57] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:420    "rpc"   "clangd-12" "stderr"    "V[06:25:57.138] Dex query tree: (LIMIT 10000 (& T=lex T=exi T=pio T=tpi T=itp T=xit T=oct T=ctl T=tle T=ioc S= ?=Restricted For Code Completion))\n"
```

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is without seeing [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs)

Comment: How can I enable verbose logs in my config?

Comment: At the clangd level, it's done by passing `--log=verbose` as a command line argument to clangd. Not sure how that's specified in the neovim config. Maybe by changing `"clangd-12"` to `"clangd-12 --log=verbose"` on the second-last line? Or maybe there's a separate argument from `cmd` for specifying arguments to the command?

Comment: @HighCommander4 `"clangd-12 --log=verbose"` doesn't work and I cant find an option in the documentation